# Adding through view trigger error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this view and the instead of trigger for inserting through view

```
CREATE VIEW LivrareNoua AS
Select numef,numec,numep,cantitate
From Furnizori F, Componente C, Proiecte P, Livrari L
Where F.idf = L.idf AND C.idc = L.idc AND P.idp = L.idp;
```

I don't know what the problem might be

```
create or replace TRIGGER triggerinstead
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON LivrareNoua
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Furnizori(idf,numef) VALUES('&idf',:new.numef);
INSERT INTO Componete(idc,numec) VALUES('&idc',:new.numec);
INSERT INTO Proiecte(idp,numep) VALUES('&idp',:new.numep);
INSERT INTO Livrari(idf,idc,idp,cantitate) VALUES('&idf','&idc','&idp',:new.cantitate);
END;
```

ERRORS:

> 3   13 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> 3  1   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: First of all you've tagged `sql-server` and `oracle`. I've removed `sql-server` as error suggest Oracle. Second thing please  post result of `desc Componente`. Error suggest that there is no column `cantitate` in `componente`

Comment: Are your running this through sqlplus?  Make sure to "set scan off"

Comment: the last table was Livrari, but still it shows that Table or view does not exist. I'm running this on oracle Apex

Comment: First, your view references a table `Componente ` but your trigger references a similarly named `Componete` without an n.  I would guess that is a typo.  Once you fix that, what do you expect `'&idf'` to be?  Are you really trying to insert that literal string into your table?  So every row will have the same `idf` value?  That seems highly unlikely.  If you are expecting that to be replaced by a `SQL*Plus` substitution variable or an APEX session variable, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the development schema is the same as the schema of the view